# Can import lxml, but can't import etree - Python

Tags: python, lxml

```
from lxml import etree
```

liClipse gives me an icon with the message "Unresolved import: etree".

However,

```
import lxml
```

is fine. Why might this be? Is there any way I can get etree just from lxml?

I'm using Python 3.5 32-bit on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

pip freeze:

```
C:\Users\daniel.bak>pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
lxml==3.6.0
queuelib==1.4.2
requests==2.9.1
selenium==2.53.1
six==1.10.0
Twisted==16.1.0
virtualenv==15.0.1
w3lib==1.14.1
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

Comment: Try just reinstalling lxml, its possible your version is outdated or corrupted

Comment: how exactly did you install `lxml`? also show us `pip freeze`

Comment: I installed lxml by downloading lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl and using "pip install". pip freeze is in the main.

Comment: `.whl` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) ?

Comment: Yes. Adding more characters.

Comment: this is weird, looks like something wrong with your build of lxml. I probably would check the versions of python, pip and redownload-reinstall the wheel while looking at verbose log of pip.

Comment: I have the same problem in a 'Mac OSX El Capitan' using `virtualenv`. Tried to install `libxml2` and the `libxslt` but it says it is installed.

Comment: I have the same problem. I uninstalled and reinstalled, nothing changed. Is there any update related to this issue?